# Python menu code move to next line of code

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple menu in python for class,      although, whenever I enter a choice in, for example, 1 - 5, I keep ending up getting my next if statement in my code which is "wrong choice,start over"
my question is why does python keep printing the next if statement in my code("wrong answer, start over") when I enter a choice from one through 5 instead of saving it and moving to the next line in my code which should be the input for income

```
def main():
    print("\t\t\tMain Menu")
    print("\t\t\t=========")
    print ("\n\t\t1- Single")
    print ("\t\t2- Jointley (Married)")
    print ("\t\t3- Married Filing Seperatley")
    print ("\t\t4- Head of HouseHold")
    print ("\t\t5- Quit")


    choice = input("\n\n\t\t\tEnter your choice : ").upper()[0]
    if (choice == '1'):
        choice = 'S'
    elif (choice == '2'):
        choice = 'J'
    elif (choice == '3'):
        choice = 'M'
    elif (choice == '4'):
        choice = 'H'
    elif (choice == '5'):
        choice = 'Q'
    if (choice != 'S' or choice != 'J' or choice != 'M' or choice != 'H' or  choice != 'Q'):
        print("wrong Choice, Start over")
    else:
        income = float (input("Enter your Gross Income from Your W-2 form:   "))


main()
input("Press Enter to Continue")
```

Answer (score 1):

For your condition here:

```
if (choice != 'S' or choice != 'J' or choice != 'M' or choice != 'H' or  choice != 'Q'):
```

You are looking to simply check whether choice is not any of the letters you expect, so you should be doing this with a `not in`:

```
if choice not in ('S', 'J', 'M', 'H', 'Q'):
```

Furthermore, for what you are doing here:

```
input("\n\n\t\t\tEnter your choice : ").upper()[0]
```

Don't have them enter the entire choice. Just the number. So you just take the input, and since it will be the string representation of a number, no need to `upper` either:

```
input("\n\n\t\t\tEnter your choice : ")
```

Comment: Thank you idjaw, you answered my question

Comment: @ocelot You are welcome. If this helped you, make sure to accept it to indicate it was helpful and solved your problem.

Comment: what exactly do i accept  to indicate it was helpful, sorry and thanks again

Comment: @ocelot No need to apologize. The checkmark next to the answer. When you select it, it will turn green to indicate you accepted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code is moving to the last `if` statement is because of the `or`.

```
if (choice != 'S' or choice != 'J' or choice != 'M' or choice != 'H' or  choice != 'Q'):
```

For example, if `choice == 'S'` is true, that means `choice != 'J'` is also true, so no matter what `choice` is, that line will result true. Changing to `and` will fix the issue.

```
if choice != 'S' and choice != 'J' and choice != 'M' and choice != 'H' and choice != 'Q':
```

---

Small example to test it:

```
>> choice = 'S'

>> print(choice == 'S')
>> print(choice != 'Q')
>> print(choice == 'Q')
>> print(choice != 'S' or choice != 'Q')

True
True
False
True
```

Also, no need for parentheses for your `if` statements in Python, they're redundant.